# AngularJS: Navigate passing GET parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am familiar with using `$state.go`, and passing variables which are then accessible through `$stateParams`, as follows:

`$state.go('some.route', {id:'12'});`

How would I however, go about directing the browser to a route while passing around GET parameters? Currently I'm performing the following, which I know is not the most "angular" way to do this:

`window.location = '#/my/path?id=12';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your state url as so `url: '#/my/path?id'`

use it like `$stage.go('some.route', {id: '12'});`

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back to you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with passing around prams like that, just add a href attribute on the item you want to be your link and you should be fine.

```
href="#/my_view/{{data._id}}
```

so in this case you add the href attribute and by clicking it you will go to the view where the id is like your $scope._id

is this the kind of thing you mean (maybe i'm misreading)?